# location updates on background app

Tags: android, location, google-maps-android-api-2

i want to add the feature to update the location ***when i put the app in background***, because i noticed that it doesn't call `onLocationChanged()` if i resume my app in a different location,how i can change this code to do that?

```
public class MapsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, OnInfoWindowClickListener {

    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000;

    private Button button;
    private GoogleMap map = null;
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private Location myLocation;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LatLng newPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL).setSmallestDisplacement(10);
        if (locationClient != null)
            // connect the client to the Google Play services
            locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        newPosition = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        myLocation = location;
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newPosition, 14));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, this);
    }
    [...]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a wrong approach because activity is not available in background mode. You have de  do it through a service class

Comment: @malcubierre can you provide me a guide on how to do that.

Comment: Google tutorials... https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html